# Hindi text support in scrapy shell on windows

Tags: windows-10, command-line, fonts

I am scraping some hindi website for my assignment. In that process when i am using scrappy shell i wish to see what content i am getting. But it seems like there is no hindi support. I have installed different hindi font in the system thinking it might solve the issue but nothing improve.
My operating system is windows 10.

Is seeing hindi text actually in hindi possible on the scrapy shell(windows command prompt)? Should i just move on and work with the wild estimations.

Comment: Set the correct code page. See [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) - Change the active console Code Page. The default code page is determined by the Windows Locale.

Comment: i have set chcp to  65001. It should support hindi in utf-8 but nothing happening in cmd. also utf-8 it is working fine with notepad.

Comment: Does it work in a normal `cmd`shell?

Comment: How are you displaying the scraped text?

Comment: No it's not working in cmd. but after storing in text file i am able to see it.

Comment: I think the best way is to switch to ubuntu. It has a better unicode support than window.